# What are these tiny pieces of metal that came with my Giant TCR Advanced 2?

Tags: parts

Last year I bought a 2016 Giant TCR Advanced 2. With the documentation in a small plastic bag came these two small pieces of metal with a spongy sticker on them.

[image]
[image]

One is slightly curved the other is flat.[image]

What is their purpose?

Comment: Hahaha. I was going to say they look like currency coins to me! ... until I realized you included the money just for size purposes.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question, but curious... Is that the British 50p piece?

Comment: @FreeMan it's a 20p coin

Comment: Thank you, @yjo. I've often heard British F1 commentators describing a flat-spotted tire as being like a 50p piece so I thought this was it. I guess I'll just have to Google an image for myself to see the difference...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are to protect your frame from the support bolt on Shimano front derailleurs (I don't know if SRAM have the same).

You can see them on page page 7 of [this manual](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-FD0002-05-ENG.pdf).

Comment: Nice, certainly one of the more niche parts!